# Skype opening as 4.0 after I have installed 4.3

Tags: 12.04, files, skype, delete

I had skype 4.0 installed for ubuntu 12,but go a cannot connect to server error while trying to login. I looked it up and more people updated it to 4.3 by removing the file via terminal. It said it removed the file but I am unsure if it was the right command I put in. I kept going and installed skype 4.3 for ubuntu. After the install I opened skype to find it still opened as 4.0. I am confused and this is probably a repeat. If so direct me to where I can be helped please. Thanks.

Comment: tried it, still opens skype 4.0.0.8 instead of 4.3 and still gives me server connect failed

Comment: @P.-H.Lin: Please do **not** make this a duplicate. It's a specific issue worth an own question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Removed, thanks, but to be frankly, I saw this kind of question over and over again, reporter get this fixed with steps indicated in that post.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin: Fair enough. Thanks for removing it.

Answer (score 2):

You hit https://launchpad.net/bugs/1372846

Install `skype-bin` too, and you'll probably notice a difference.